# Can I disable my 2009 Volvo S40's remote key fob panic button?

Tags: volvo, key, fob

The panic button on the [remote key fob](http://amzn.com/B00I1MQXL4) is very sensitive and sets off the alarm accidentally all the time, for example, when it's in my pocket and I move a certain way.

Is there a way to disable the panic button, or do they make a key fob that works with the 2009 S40 that does not have the panic button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to disable it would be to take the fob apart and put a very small piece of tape on the contacts for the button. This would make it so you could reverse this without too much issue if you decided to sell the car. Most car fobs (at least like the one you show in the link) will split in two to replace the battery. This also gives you access to the electronics. Placing the bit of tape between where the button makes contact should make it so it will no longer be able to do this. If (and I know, big ***IF***) you can get the fob apart, it should be readily apparent to you what I'm talking about. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it through disabling it electronically inside the car or the Body Control Module (BCM). This would probably require you to take it to the dealership to accomplish (with some sort of computer which would talk to your vehicle).